# Can Python's distutils compile .S (assembly)?

Tags: python, distutils

I wrote a small Python extension that bundles, compiles and statically links with a small C library with one optional .S (assembler) file. Distutils's Extension() doesn't recognize the .S by default. Is there a good way to compile that file, or should I just shell out to `make`? Right now I compile the C code only for a slightly slower library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how new it is, but the `Extension` class has an [`extra_objects`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/ext_modules.html#extension-api-reference) argument, which I found can specify assembly files. So for example, my `setup.py` looks something like this:

```
example_module = Extension('_example',
    extra_compile_args = ['-Wall', '-g', '-std=c++11'],
    sources=['something.cpp'],
    extra_objects=['asm_amd64.s'])
```

I double checked, and if you inspect the generated library with `nm -D example.so`, the assembly functions are properly assembled and linked if you include it in the `extra_objects`, but they are not linked if you don't include it in that argument. So it seems to work.

Comment: For those using CFFI rather than a raw C `Extension`, note that you *can* still use `extra_objects` for `.S` blobs and whatnot—to do this, you have to pass it as a keyword argument to [`ffibuilder.set_source()`](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.16/cdef.html#ffibuilder-set-source-preparing-out-of-line-modules).

Answer (score 2):

As distributed, distutils don't know about assembly code, and I don't know of extensions to it that let it deal automatically with it.  In a similar situation I've always built the library separately (with C and assembly as needed and feasible) and only used the resulting `.a` with setup.py.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open feature request about this: http://bugs.python.org/issue2942